# List duplicate keys in jquery typeahead.js

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I have a HTML form where the user is supposed to fill "city" and "state" inputs. The "city" input is backed by typeahead.js and when the user selects a city from the list, both "city" and "state" are updated:

```
<input id="city" name="city" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
<input id="state" name="state" type="text"/>
```

...

```
var $typeaheadCity = $("#city").typeahead({
    name: "city",
    valueKey: "city",
    remote: "../servlet/SearchCity?q=%QUERY",
    template: '<p>{{city}}, {{state}}</p>',
    engine: Hogan
});
$typeaheadCity.on("typeahead:selected", function(obj, datum, name) {
    $("#state").val(datum.state);
});
```

It works as intended unless I have cities with the same name but in different states. In this case only the first occurrence is listed and the others won't be available for selection. For example consider the following response from the server:

```
[
    { "city": "Campinas", "state": "AC" },
    { "city": "Campinas", "state": "RS" },
    { "city": "Campinas", "state": "SP" },
    { "city": "Campinas do Piaui", "state": "PI" },
    { "city": "Campinas do Sul", "state": "RS" }
]
```

The typeahead list will be populated only with

```
Campinas, AC
Campinas do Piaui, PI
Campinas do Sul, RS
```

I implemented a workaround to include an unique id for each city, set "id" as "valueKey" and on "typeahead:selected" event to update "city" input with the city name over the id. But this workaround breaks the autocomplete feature of typeahead and when the user navigates in the list, the input value is overwritten with the "unfriendly" id code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that typeahead removes duplicate items by default, and, also by default, the uniqueness of an item is determined by the "valueKey" field.

I think it might only be in the latest beta version, but it looks like [typehead now has a dataset option named "dupChecker"](https://gist.github.com/jharding/5996735), which allows you to provide a function that will be used to determine the uniqueness of items.

From [this change request](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/215), it looks like the "dupChecker" option was added just for a situation like yours.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. As a quick fix I did as in [Adding an option for allowing duplicates to show in the dataset](https://github.com/willtcarey/typeahead.js/commit/bd6d080d69895d6c062df8f78e4f1c4efc0b76f3)